# Replace points with hexagons in map ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

On a map, I'm trying to replace points with hexagons but can't. I've tried using `geom_hex` but I don't get the same result,
Any suggestions?

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, color = value), linewidth = 1, na.rm = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c('#80146E','#804AA4','#6771B8','#379BC2',
                                     '#3ABCBF','#79D4B8','white','#FCEE88','#F8C34B', 
                                     '#F7A72B', '#F4792D'),
                         values = scales::rescale(-10, -8, -6, -4, -2, -1, 0, 
                                                    0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1))) + 
  theme_void() + 
  coord_map()
```

[image]

edit

```
df <- head(df)
dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(-1.29180627034999, -1.19180627074999, -1.09180627114999, 
-0.991806271549991, -0.891806271949991, -0.791806272349991), 
    y = c(44.24152724085, 44.24152724085, 44.24152724085, 44.24152724085, 
    44.24152724085, 44.24152724085), value = c(-0.709841088006482, 
    -0.889560720544426, -0.998504169250709, -0.905970350930832, 
    -0.888156362836211, -0.960843878765758)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share your `df`? You can use `dput`. If it's too big, just provide a minimal part of it

Comment: that said, I would try to use `st_make_grid(points, square = FALSE)` which creates an hexagonal grid

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've added the `head` of my `df` in edit (else `df` is much too long). However, it's not possible to use `st_make_grid()` with `ggplot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can approximate your data by getting a raster of France with altitude data, downsampling it and converting to x, y, z format.

```r
df <- raster::getData('alt', country = 'FRA', mask = TRUE) |>
  raster::aggregate(fact = 15) |>
  raster::rasterToPoints() |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  setNames(c('x', 'y', 'value'))
```

The plot using your code with these points looks something like this - similar to your own image but with different colors due to the different values

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = value)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0.8) +
  theme_void() + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c('#80146E','#804AA4','#6771B8','#379BC2',
                                     '#3ABCBF','#79D4B8','white','#FCEE88',
                                     '#F8C34B', '#F7A72B', '#F4792D'),
                         values = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.85,
                                    0.9, 0.95, 1)) +
  coord_map()
```

[image]

If you want to switch to hexagons, you will need `stat_hex_summary`, with `fun = mean` and `aes(z = value)`. Remember also to change your `scale_color_gradientn` to `scale_fill_gradientn`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, z = value)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun = mean, color = 'white', bins = 60) +
  theme_void() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c('#80146E','#804AA4','#6771B8','#379BC2',
                                     '#3ABCBF','#79D4B8','white','#FCEE88',
                                     '#F8C34B', '#F7A72B', '#F4792D'),
                         values = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8, 0.85,
                                    0.9, 0.95, 1)) +
  coord_map()
```

[image]

If you want larger or smaller hexagons, decrease or increase the number of `bins`.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!